# Strapi not able to filter relations value

Tags: strapi

I have two collection. post and common. I have defined `common has many Post` relation. The relation is called `contains`.

Post as component called place with country field, which is enumeration with country codes ( two character)
So relations will have posts which might have different countries.
I trying to filter the relations values. What I want is,the relation field should only have posts with specific country code.

**What i have tried**

`/api/commons?populate[0]=contains.basic&populate[1]=basic&filters[contains][place][country][$eq]=AF&populate[2]=contains.place`

But for this the relation will have posts that have different country codes.

Is it possible to filter the relations values? Or is there better way to structure this?

Comment: Hi, not sure i fully understand your data layout, it's usually not a good idea to filter relations.... much better if you just to /api/posts?filters[$and][0][common][$eq]=commonId&filters[$and][1][country][$eq]=AF

Comment: const str = qs.stringify(
  {
    filters: {
      $and: [
        {
          common: {
            $eq: "commonId"
          }
        },
        {
          country: {
            $eq: "AF"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { encodeValuesOnly: true }
);

Comment: @antokhio Thank you! I should have thought about this. `populate=*&filters[$and][0][common][id][$eq]=5&filters[$and][1][place][country][$eq]=IN` This worked  for me. Feel free to answer. I will mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure i fully understand your data layout, however it seems that instead filtering the relation of `Common` you would get the data more easily if you just filter the posts:

```
/api/posts?filters[$and][0][common][$eq]=commonId&filters[$and][1][country][$eq]=AF
```

with query:

```
    const str = qs.stringify(
        {
            filters: {
                $and: [{ common: { $eq: 'commonId' } }, { country: { $eq: 'AF' } }],
            },
        },
        { encodeValuesOnly: true }
    );
```